# How to troubleshoot Linux in-kernel dns_resolver

Tags: linux, server-message-block, cifs, dfs

Linux provides a facility that lets kernel and its modules to resolve DNS names by relying on user-space tools. This, for example, is used by CIFS to support referrals in the DFS.

The problem I'm seeing is that I can't get the kernel to resolve a specific DNS name and I don't understand why it fails.

To understand the root cause I have enabled debug output in both, CIFS and kernel dns resolver by running following commands:

```
echo "1" >  /sys/module/dns_resolver/parameters/debug  # dns_resolver
echo "7" > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI  # CIFS
```

Here's what I see in dmesg when the failure occurs:

```
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: ref path: \ESOTEST\dfstest\FS_SERV
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: node path: \FS\FS_SERV
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: fl: 2, srv_type: 0
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: ref_flags: 0, path_consumed: 24
fs/cifs/netmisc.c: address conversion returned 0 for FS
fs/cifs/netmisc.c: address conversion returned 0 for FS
[ls    ] ==> dns_query((null),FS,2,(null))
fs/cifs/dns_resolve.c: dns_resolve_server_name_to_ip: unable to resolve: FS
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: cifs_compose_mount_options: Failed to resolve server part of \\FS\FS_SERV to IP:
```

-22

And this is the output of a successful resolution:

```
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: node path: \ESOTEST\File-Server
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: fl: 2, srv_type: 0
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: DFS: ref_flags: 0, path_consumed: 28
fs/cifs/netmisc.c: address conversion returned 0 for ESOTEST
fs/cifs/netmisc.c: address conversion returned 0 for ESOTEST
[ls    ] ==> dns_query((null),ESOTEST,7,(null))
[ls    ] call request_key(,ESOTEST,)
[ls    ] ==> dns_resolver_match(ESOTEST,ESOTEST)
[ls    ] <== dns_resolver_match() = 1
[ls    ] <== dns_query() = 14
fs/cifs/dns_resolve.c: dns_resolve_server_name_to_ip: resolved: ESOTEST to 192.168.56.102
fs/cifs/cifsfs.c: Devname: \\ESOTEST\File-Server flags: 0
```

I am using Windows as the DNS server and I can resolve the name "FS" from the machine:

```
$ ping FS
PING FS.esodomain.com (192.168.56.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fs.esodomain.com (192.168.56.104): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.37 ms
64 bytes from fs.esodomain.com (192.168.56.104): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.630 ms
```

I have also tried using key.dns_resolver to manually perform a test and it seems to work:

```
$ key.dns_resolver -vv -D "FS" 'hello'
I: Key description: 'dns_resolver;-1;-1;0;FS'
I: Callout info: 'hello'
D: Get A/AAAA RR for hostname:'FS', options:'hello'
D: Opt hello
D: Resolve 'FS' with 1ff
D: getaddrinfo = 0
D: RR: 0,2,1,6,10,(null)
D: append '192.168.56.104'
I: The key instantiation data is '192.168.56.104'
```

Contents of /etc/request-key.conf are:

```
create  dns_resolver *      *               /sbin/key.dns_resolver %k
create  user    debug:*     negate      /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
create  user    debug:*         rejected        /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:*         expired         /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:*         revoked         /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:loop:*    *       |/bin/cat
create  user    debug:*     *       /usr/share/keyutils/request-key-debug.sh %k %d %c %S
negate  *   *       *       /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
```

The reason I am fiddling with this is that I'm trying to get a Windows DFS share to mount successfully. I am able to mount and access folders that are hosted on the root server but when I try to access a sub-folder which refers to an external server I get:

```
ls: cannot access /mnt/dfstest/FS_SERV/: Invalid argument
```

I'm on 3.7.10 kernel:

```
Linux gentoo 3.7.10-gentoo-r1 #3 SMP Fri Apr 19 17:32:20 PDT 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

In a network capture I don't see any DNS requests for "FS" while I see a request for "ESOTEST". This suggests that the request is not ever made.

What next steps would you recommend to troubleshoot this?

Comment: As I cannot +10 this, I'm awarding +100 bounty to you for this one.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be caused by the Linux kernel. Specifically, by the dns_resolver. "FS" is not even attempted at resolution.

The following lines in dns_resolver (net/dns_resolver/dns_query.c) seem to cause this:

```
if (namelen < 3)
    return -EINVAL;
```

I don't know why there is this check. I will try renaming the other server from "FS" to something longer. I will try recompiling the kernel with this check removed.

**UPDATE: yes, that was the reason and it works after re-naming the hostname to a longer name**

Answer (score 0):

Also, [apparently](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1937#issuecomment-297762011) the kernel dns_resolver does not honor TTL.
[To clear the kernel's DNS cache](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1937#issuecomment-297962580):

```
sudo keyctl clear $((16#$(sudo cat /proc/keys | grep .dns_resolver | awk '{print $1;}')))
```